# Accessing Conversation data from Message Controller c#

Tags: c#, botframework

I have been using the context.setvalue(); and context.TryGetvalue(); to store and receive data to different storages in Bot Framework.

I want to know how we can access this values from MessageController.cs

Already tried creating a New object, it don't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this post when searching for another answer I posted.  I wanted anyone that comes here in the future to know the correct way to do this.

`StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();` gets the **Default** state client only which is deprecated as of March 31st 2018.  It has been replaced by an in-memory state store.  If you have implemented your own state client (i.e. cosmosDB, Azure table storage, SQL, etc etc) the proper way to access state in the messages controller is something along the lines of this:

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
{

    var message = activity as IMessageActivity;
    using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
    {
        var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();
        var key = Address.FromActivity(message);

        ConversationReference r = new ConversationReference();
        var userData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, CancellationToken.None);

        //set state data
        userData.SetProperty("key 1", "value1");
        userData.SetProperty("key 2", "value2");
        //get state data
        userData.GetProperty<string>("key 1");
        userData.GetProperty<string>("key 2");

        await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
        await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a weird `System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Autofac.IContainer Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.get_Container()'.`  exception. using Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.15. Decompiling the DLL (JetBrains dotPeek), to my horror, the `Conversation` class is missing! Anyone else getting this? @AlokRajasukumaran ?

Answer (score 5):

To get the conversation data you either need a reference to the context or get a state client from the activity.

Inside the Dialog you can use the context:
http://robinosborne.co.uk/2016/08/08/persisting-data-within-a-conversation-with-botframeworks-dialogs/

Outside of a Dialog you can use the activity to get a state client:

```
StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
if (userData.GetProperty<bool>("SentGreeting"))
        // do something
```

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: so in your blog and post your saying private convo is what need to use over normal conversation data?

Comment: i tried this method already but it did not help much to send data from message controller.

Comment: What am asking is inside the messaegcontroller.cs

Comment: Yep, outside of a Dialog (i.e., in your MessagesController) you can use the stateClient - the 2nd part of my answer: StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();

Comment: Okay, i juts moved the data point to an idialog. thanks for your answer.