# How can I access Bot Framework ConversationData outside of a dialog like in messages controller?

Tags: c#, botframework

In a dialog within my bot, I store a flag value in the ConversationData like so:

```
context.ConversationData.SetValue("SomeFlag", true);
```

Later, I need to check that flag in my MessagesController, *before* the message is dispatched to a dialog. As per [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328134/accessing-conversation-data-from-message-controller-c-sharp) I tried retrieving the ConversationData in via the StateClient like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity incomingMessage)
{
    StateClient stateClient = incomingMessage.GetStateClient();
    BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetConversationDataAsync(message.ChannelId, message.Conversation.Id);
    bool finishedQuote = userData.GetProperty<bool>("SomeFlag");
    //...
    // do conditional logic, then dispatch to a dialog as normal
}
```

However, at runtime, the `userData` variable holds a BotData object where `userData.Data` is null, and I'm unable to retrieve any stored flags via `GetProperty`. I don't see anything in the [relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state) that helps shed light on this issue - what might I be doing wrong here? Is there something I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work for what you need:

```
if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
{

    var message = activity as IMessageActivity;
    using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
    {
        var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();
        var key = Address.FromActivity(message);

        ConversationReference r = new ConversationReference();
        var userData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, CancellationToken.None);

        //you can get/set UserData, ConversationData, or PrivateConversationData like below
        //set state data
        userData.SetProperty("key 1", "value1");
        userData.SetProperty("key 2", "value2");
        //get state data
        userData.GetProperty<string>("key 1");
        userData.GetProperty<string>("key 2");

        await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
        await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect! Just changed it to load ConversationData rather than UserData and it did exactly what I needed!

Answer (score -1):

Initialize BotState object with StateClient as below. Try the below code

```
   public static T GetStateData<T>(Activity activity, string key)
    {
        BotState botState = new BotState(activity.GetStateClient());
        BotData botData = botState.GetConversationData(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id);
        return botData.GetProperty<T>(key);
    }
```

Comment: This did not work - it results in the same outcome as the snippet posted in my question.

Comment: to test it try harcoding "activity.ChannelId" to "webchat" and give any fixed value for conversation while saving and retrieving. Any specific reason to save in ConversationData? You can also try UserData, PrivateConversationData etc

Comment: I'm not using webchat, I'm using the Bot Framework Emulator - and I don't think that loading UserData or PrivateConversationData would be any different, since they're loaded the same way. I appreciate the attempt, but the accepted solution from JasonSowers above works perfectly.

Comment: activity.GetStateClient() is deprecated.  It will retrieve the default state client, intended only for prototyping: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/18/saving-state-azure-extensions/