# Migration of BotState to Azure Table Storage: no more possibility to access UserData without IDialogContext?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I recently switched my custom state data from the now deprecated `StateClient` to Azure Table Storage using [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365), following the steps:

- Created a storage
- Added to connection strings
- Added to Autofac registration in Global.asax.cs

This is working well for all call like `context.UserData.SetValue("myKey", "myValue");` inside dialogs.

But it seems that there is no more possibility to get `UserData` directly from an `Activity` object when we have no `IDialogContext`, for example if you want to use these data from your MessageController.

Previously, I was doing:

```
var botState = activity.GetStateClient().BotState;
var userData = await botState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, token);
```

These actions are announced as deprecated in latest BotBuilder release. Any solution to do the equivalent?

EDIT:

Adding my global.asax.cs:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //register the bot builder module
        builder.RegisterModule(new DialogModule());

        //register project dependencies
        builder.RegisterModule(new BotModule());

        //Http config 
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        //register controller
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //create container
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

And the BotModule associated:

```
public class BotModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        // Scorable pour l'interruption de dialogue
        builder.Register(c => new InterruptScorable(c.Resolve<IDialogTask>())).As<IScorable<IActivity, double>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        
        // Manage BotData in Sql Datatable
        var store = new TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationHelper.XXXXX, "BotData");
        builder.Register(c => store).Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store, CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.ETagBasedConsistency)).As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Logger de conversation
        builder.Register(c => new ActivityLogger(c.Resolve<IBotData>())).As<IActivityLogger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Dialogue de base
        builder.RegisterType<RootDialog>().As<IDialog<object>>().InstancePerDependency();
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085614/how-can-i-access-bot-framework-conversationdata-outside-of-a-dialog/46085785#46085785), it should help you :)

Comment: @JasonSowers thanks I was looking into something similar but did not got my data in Azure Table after flush call. Is it normal?

Comment: Doesn't seem normal, mind posting a snippet so we can take a look?

Comment: I tested it further yesterday and my conclusion is: it's working but the data is in the table after an initial message from the user. And the data is not consistent with `context.UserData` values... I think I have to prepare a code sample to show this

Comment: Can you post your Global.asax.cs?  There's actually nothing happening in the .Flush for Azure Table Storage: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/0571e46159be56b725e23d87174465fd3a6de632/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/TableBotDataStore.cs#L162  The persistence in the table storage implementation is done in SaveAsync, and should be in the Azure Table after SaveAsync is called.  Flush is on the interface for other implementations.

Comment: @EricDahlvang: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code a little, to remove the deprecated **.Build()** method.

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new DialogModule());
            builder.RegisterModule<BotModule>();
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        });

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(Conversation.Container);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

After registering the modules this way, the code Jason Sowers shared on this issue should help: [How can I access Bot Framework ConversationData outside of a dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085614/how-can-i-access-bot-framework-conversationdata-outside-of-a-dialog/46085785#46085785)

Comment: Thanks Eric. I have to edit the question to show the problem I got next: the data is not consistent between the access with Jason's solution and context.UserData values.

Comment: Eric, I set the answer as accepted for this point, will open a new question about the consistency next time