# In the MS Bot Framework, Is there a way to prompt for sensitive info, such as username/passwords, cc numbers etc?

Tags: botframework, bots

As the question states, I'd like to have a user be able to enter something, such as username/password, to the Bot and make sure that the data is encrypted, and also be able to decrypt it (for immediate use only) using a built-in Bot framework encrypt/decrypt method where the secret key is hidden from me (the programmer). Basically I'd to be able to do something like:

string result = await activity;
string sensitiveInfo = Dialog.Decrypt(result.text);

Is there some way to tell a Dialog or the context to encrypt an activity?

This way if there is an activity logger logging chats sensitive chat info is not stored in plain text.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the data that sent from channel client is encrypted and the data could be decrypted in bot application dialog?

Comment: Generally, I give a link to a web page where user can submit the info. Once successful I send a proactive message to the user like *congratulations, signup completed* on bot (which sometimes trigger a message notification too) which indicates that the operation has completed, and user should now continue with the bot. Also give the same message on the web page also. Do note that no channel support masking the text, so if you take password from user in the channel itself, it will be visible in the chat history.

Comment: @Fei I don't want all data encrypted. My main issue is I have an IActivityLogger that logs all chats to a database in plain text. I'm trying to figure out someway to indicate to the activity logger not to log certain messages. I was hoping there was some way within something like the PromptDialog to tell it to encrypt the users input.

Another route I was trying was setting a flag in the
``context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<bool>("doNotLog", true);``

But I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve that value from an IActivity object

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in feature in bot framework that does encryption/decryption, you would have to write that piece yourself.

As for flagging a message for logging or not,  you would probably be best using `channelData` rather than one of the state databags  This is because the channel data is not associated with state data and only with the activity.

In your comment, you say "But I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve that value from an IActivity object"  Well, you cant directly from the activity object itself.  You would have to end up doing something like whats in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085614/how-can-i-access-bot-framework-conversationdata-outside-of-a-dialog) if you were in a controller or something other than a dialog (like your implementation of `IActivityLogger`).  However, when you save your data in `channelData` it is directly accessible from the `Activity`/`IActivity` object like `activity.ChannelData...`.  Channel Data is a (JSON) object you can use to store any data you want and can also be used to send channel specific data to a channel to use the custom features of that channel.

Comment: Yes, I understand that could work for outgoing messages, messages from the bot to the user. But how would I alter the ChannelData of the Activity the user sends to the bot?

Comment: You would only be able to do that with something like directLine or webchat where you could customize the front end (channel) to do what you need