# How to Implement a Session Variable on MS Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I'm searching for guidance about how to implement a session-level variable on bot framework.

I've created a class to store global vars that is working fine.

However, these variables are persisted across all bot sessions which is not what I need now.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Ed Y - Can you give some more detail about what you are using the variables for?

Comment: I need session variables to store customer-specific data such as CustomerID and other app parameters that are stored on a SQL DB

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of you are using the Node or the C# SDK.  You can easily store data like this in the Databags provided by the SDK.  `UserData`, `ConversationData`, and `PrivateConversationData`

For the purposes of just demonstrating how to use this i'm only going to use `UserData` but any databag could be used the same way

---

### Node

For node, you would set values as if you were using a dictionary or hashmap in other languages:

You can use either dot notation or bracket notation:

```
session.userData.SomeProperty = "someValue";
session.userData["SomeProperty"] = "someValue"
```

And then to use the data later, again you can use either dot notation or bracket notation:

```
var foo = session.userData.SomeProperty;
var foo = session.userData["SomeProperty"]
```

---

### C#

To set Data:

```
context.UserData.SetValue("SomeProperty", "SomeValue");
```

To get data:

```
context.UserData.GetValue<string>("SomeProperty");
```

In C# if you need to do this in a place you do not have access to the context object refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328134/accessing-conversation-data-from-message-controller-c-sharp/49784647#49784647)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Jason. Just come back from holidays. Thanks a million for your help. Finding a way to manage state variables out of the  context object was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome, please accept and upvote if this answers your question, good luck.